# How to get component code in react-native output

Tags: android, error-handling, react-native, react-native-component

I have created button component for my app.

Here is my code

```
 <TouchableOpacity 
 style={{ width: 200, height: 40, backgroundColor: '#000', justifyContent: 
 'center', alignSelf: 'center' }}>
  <Text style={{ color: '#ffffff', justifyContent: 'center', alignSelf: 
  'center'}}>
    Button
  </Text>
 </TouchableOpacity
```

[image]

`i want to see second output not the first one`

Answer (score 3):

i have seen your code and i m trying to find your answer.
you can use the `<Text>` tag in your code and inside this tag you can place your component in `<Text>` tag with {``} this braces and back-ticks . you can place you code in the back-ticks and that will work. if you trouble in this answer feel free to ask again.
Please try this if it helpful for you.
thank you.